# how to override on activityResult in android

Tags: android, facebook, overriding, onactivityresult

I get this code from the facebook document [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
       // @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
            Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
            Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
        }
    });
}
```

and put it in the MainActivity, but the eclipse gives errors:`The method onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall, Bundle) of type new FacebookDialog.Callback(){} must override or implement a supertype method` and `The method onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall, Bundle) of type new FacebookDialog.Callback(){} must override or implement a supertype method` etc, why?

Comment: What happens when you remove the @Override?

Answer (score 0):

to follow the tutorial you are pointing out you need to do follow the Prerequisits part. You have to have all the Facebook Login tutorial implemented to continue with the sharing.

The piece of code I have for the particual method you are pointing out is similar to yours:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(activity, requestCode, resultCode, data);

    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback(){
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data){
            Log.e(activity.getClass().getName(), String.format("Error %s", error.toString()));
        }

        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data){
            Log.i(activity.getClass().getName(), "Success!!!");

        }
    });
}
```

The only differences I see for the method is that I don't call super, and the use of Session.getActiveSession()... that comes from the Facebook Login tutorial I mentioned.

Aditionally check you have the latest facebook sdk. I am working with version 3.8.